# Can I use adb to change the default app to open certain files?

Tags: android, adb

Since the update to MIUI 14, it seems that I can no longer decide which application to use to open certain files (for example, PDFs). The option "Always open with" has disappeared, and instead, I have to choose the app every single time.

So i was thinking to fix the problem using ADB